# AttributeError: module 'embed storage' has no attribute 'help_command'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, attributeerror

I have this module I made for a discord.py bot (not a COG though). It clearly has the function "help_command" defined but whenever I try to run it it gives me the above error. I couldn't wrap my head around it so I thought it might worth it to ask the community.

`discord_main.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import gsheet
import os
import embed_storage

async def help(ctx, argument='Helping'):
    await ctx.send(embed=embed_storage.help_command('stargazer', argument))
```

`embed_storage.py`

```
import discord
from cogs.points import points_help_dict
from discord_main import help_dictionary
import gsheet

def help_command(cog_name: str, command: str):
    if cog_name == 'stargazer':
        use_dict = help_dictionary
        title = 'Help'
        description = 'Learn how the Stargazer Bot works'
        footer_message = 'Prefix for this bot is \'a\''
        else:
            raise UnboundLocalError(
                "Yeh this part of the code should have never run.")
    command = command.lower()
    if command in use_dict:
        title = command.title()
        description = use_dict[command]
        field = False

    help_command_embed = discord.Embed(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(234, 255, 208)
    )
    return help_command_embed
```

Any help would be amazing. Also sorry for the dumb question. Just couldn't wrap my head around this silly error.

Edit: Tried Rolling back to my latest working version of the code and when I ran that. It still gave me the same error. So the error is not in the newly added code

Comment: It's starting to look like you have mutual imports. Could you update your question to show all your imports as well?

Comment: Would importing the same module twice (once in discord_main.py and another in embed_storage.py) cause this error?

Comment: Python Version 3.8.1

Comment: That didn't work, Discord automatically closed the session. But I realized that I don't really need the help dictionary in `discord_main.py`. A simple Ctrl + C, Ctrl + v of the dictionary fixed the problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are importing from `discord_main` in `embed_storage` and vice-versa.

You need to resolve this somehow or, if there is no other way, you could move the import into the function definition, e.g. in `embed_storage.py`:

```py
def help_command(cog_name: str, command: str):
    from discord_main import help_dictionary
    if cog_name == 'stargazer':
        use_dict = help_dictionary
# ...
```

Comment: Got the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'help_command' from 'embed_storage' (C:\Users\Aryan Garg\PycharmProjects\StarGrazer\embed_storage.py)`

Comment: Are you doing the import in your `discord_main.py`?

Comment: Yes. I am importing embed_storage into discord_main.py